# How to access private Fusion Table from App Engine cron job?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-fusion-tables

I have created several private tables in Fusion Table. These tables should be accessed and modified regularly by a cron job from my App Engine java web app. Could you please point me to  example code or give me some guidance? And to be clear - I do not want users of my web app to gain access to the private tables, just the cron job should have access.

Regards,
Dimitar Bonev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found what I was looking for:
http://ddewaele.blogspot.com/2011/05/google-fusion-tables-api-first.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use ClientLogin (needs email and password :( ) or get a valid oauth token from an account with access to the tables and store it in the server, so only the cron job can access it, I used this method in my app.

some info: http://code.google.com/apis/fusiontables/docs/developers_guide.html#Authentication

cya.

Comment: I've heard for those two methods, but my account is two-phase authentication enabled, so I'm doubt that email and password are sufficient for ClientLogin. I'm not sure if I can programmatically get an oauth token, but I'll make a research, because OAuth is preferred to ClientLogin in general.

Answer (score 0):

Access can be restricted even for web applications with a paid service 'Google Maps for Business'
http://www.google.com/enterprise/mapsearth/

For private tables, following doc says, "Only the owner and editors have access to your table. Visualizations embedded in other websites and Google Earth network links cannot authenticate to Fusion Tables when they call for data, so the table must be Public or Unlisted for these features to work."
https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/using#authTbl